# Wrong number of rows in result when using LSTM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lstm

I want to use LSTM to predict future data. I have a total of 50 rows of data. The data in `demo_1.csv` looks like this:

```
Nnmber
0.72
0.695
1.131
1.16
1.062
0.825
0.798
1.004
1.126
0.856
0.619
0.682
0.628
0.592
0.753
0.671
0.643
0.742
0.899
0.875
0.732
0.724
0.853
0.902
0.97
0.921
1.007
1.162
0.961
1
0.985
1.131
1.276
1.147
0.692
0.697
0.721
0.611
0.685
0.669
0.83
1.03
1.021
1.046
1.053
1.038
1.129
1.157
1.167
1.249
```

This is the data of the past 50 hours. I want to use these 50 rows data to predict the results of the next 3 hours.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,SimpleRNN, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


df_1 = pd.read_csv(r'./demo_1.csv')
dataset = df_1.values
dataset = df_1.astype('float32')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train = dataset

batch_size = 5
length = 10
num_features = 1
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train,train,length=length,batch_size=batch_size)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(length, num_features)))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, verbose=2, epochs=10)
trainPredict = model.predict(train_generator,verbose=0)
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(train)

pd.DataFrame(trainY_inverse).to_csv(r'./result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')

#calculate mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY_inverse[length:], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
```

But I find the output in `result.csv` is the same as `demo_1.csv`.

The result in result.csv:

```
0
0.72
0.695
1.131
1.16
1.062
0.825
0.798
1.004
1.126
0.856
0.619
0.682
0.628
0.592
0.753
0.671
0.643
0.742
0.899
0.875
0.732
0.724
0.853
0.902
0.97
0.921
1.007
1.162
0.961
1
0.985
1.131
1.276
1.147
0.692
0.697
0.721
0.611
0.685
0.669
0.83
1.03
1.021
1.046
1.053
1.038
1.129
1.157
1.167
1.249
```

Shouldn't the result be 3 rows? That is the result of the next 3 hours, why is my result 50 rows?

I use this code,and the result is right.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,SimpleRNN, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

df_1 = pd.read_csv(r'demo_1.csv')
train = df_1.to_numpy()
batch_size = 5
length = 10
num_features = 1
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train,train,length=length,batch_size=batch_size)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(length, num_features)))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, verbose=2, epochs=10)

trainPredict = model.predict(np.expand_dims(train,axis=0))
trainPredict = trainPredict.reshape(-1, 1)
print(trainPredict)
pd.DataFrame(trainPredict).to_csv(r'./result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are exporting `trainY_inverse` to csv not `trainPredict`!

Change to `pd.DataFrame(trainPredict).to_csv(r'./result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: Sorry,I tried,but the result is not right.

Comment: what are you getting? i tried your same code in colab and i am result with shape 40,3